# Enter keypress does not work in datepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, datepicker, keypress

How make enter keypress work after user input data in datepicker jquery?

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker();

<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker " name="datepicker" id="datepicker" placeholder="27/04/2021"  required>

 $('#datepicker').keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                   ?????????????? 
                }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code reopen the datepicker **when the field has the focus**:

```
  $("#datepicker").keypress(function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
       console.log("enter key pressed");
       $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
    }
  });
```